# Concatenating columns in SQL with delimiter. If first column is null, do not want delimiter to show up after it. How do I get rid of that?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, coalesce

```
SELECT TOP 1000 places.*
    , home_Desc
    , CONCAT_WS(' - ', COALESCE(brand, ' '), home_Desc, location_Desc)  AS homeSite
```

Example:

| brand | home_Desc | location_Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blue | large | woody |
| NULL | small | forest |

So right now I am getting:

```
1.' blue - large - woody '
2. ' - small - forest '
```

But what I want for the second set is:

```
small - forest
```

Comment: You got to tag the RDBMS you are using, MSSQL , MYSQL, ORACLE ?

Comment: It is MSSQL, just added the tag

Comment: What if `home-desc` have a null, is it ok to have 2 consecutive delimiter ` -  - ` in the output?

Comment: remove the `COALESCE()` for `brand`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(brand VARCHAR(100), home_Desc VARCHAR(100), location_Desc VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('blue','large','woody'),
(NULL,'small','forest')

SELECT CONCAT_WS(' - ',brand, home_Desc, location_Desc) FROM TEST
```

As Squirrel say, you must replace **COALESCE(brand, '')** to **brand**

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the rule a non-NULL value (the dash character in this instance) concatenated with a NULL value (branch, in this instance) would yield NULL (and assuming that the other two can never be null/blank:

```
, COALESCE(brand + '-', ' ') + home_Desc + ' - ' + location_Desc AS homeSite
```